# uploading files to local server into a "safe folder" with meteor

Tags: file, upload, meteor, fileserver

I've managed to make a file uploader to the local server, with Meteor.

```
-.meteor
   -local
      -build
      -db
      -static
```

Ive write the files to the **static** folder, and everything goes fine, but whenever I restart the server, end build a new app, the local folder gets deleted along with my static folder.

Is there a safe place for files, which does not bundle with the app?
I've tried to write outside the local folder, just next to it, but when I deploy that version, the app wont start at all on the meteor server.

So where am I suppose to create a "safe folder" neither being bundled on deploy, nor deleted on restart, and still accessible apps deployed to the meteor server?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Others projects I've seen uploaded files to Amazon S3 or used something like filepicker.io. Amazon S3 is universally "safe folder" ;)

Answer (score 0):

That depends on where and how you deploy the application. If you're using a vps or similar solution that gives you access to the file system, you can:

- Write outside of the project directory, in a completely unrelated place.
- Write in a hidden directory inside the project dir. So, next to `.meteor`, but only inside another folder that begins with a `.` (like `.uploads`).

Whether or not this will work may depend on your platform.